# Like "responsible" but for things or activities

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

It's perfectly correct to say

> I'm a responsible employee.

However, what adjective should I use for non-living things or activities to convey the same meaning?

> The work is "responsible".

Meaning that the work can be done only by reliable and diligent people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Reliable:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reliable)

> - Capable of being relied on; dependable: a reliable car.

Considering your update I suggest:

[Exacting:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exacting)

> - Requiring great care, effort, or attention: an exacting task.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Josh. I have updated the question, I'm looking for the meaning "can be done only by reliable and diligent people"

Comment: +1 Apologies. I obviously resonated to your answer and substituted your term for the OP's. I have edited to include both.

Comment: @bib - no prob..will update my answer now:))

Comment: I like exacting even better.

Answer (score 1):

While somewhat more intense than *responsible* or *reliable*, you might say work or a project is *[critical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/critical)*

> Having a decisive or crucial importance in the success, failure, or existence of something

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

By implication, such important activities should only be done by *responsible* or *reliable* persons.

The term *[mission critical](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/mission-critical)* is also used to indicate that successful completion of a task is essential to success of a larger program.

> necessary for a business or other organization to work well
>   *mission-critical software*

The [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mission%20critical) characterizes this usage as *tired* and *over-used*.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider ***high-powered***.

> Involving a great deal of responsibility: *a very high-powered job* [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/high-powered)

Example:

> Going for jobs which are high-powered shows you are keen to take risks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it seems like a very nice suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

***Responsible***, as you will have gathered is used in different senses as an adjective.

One can talk about a ***responsible person***, ***responsible employee*** etc. One can also say that ***the work of an airline captain is a responsible job***, meaning it is a job which demands a high level of responsibility. Used in this sense it means the person is reliable, trustworthy and sensible.

In a different sense you can say that a particular person is ***responsible for the financial affairs of the business***. That means it is their job, their duty.

In yet another sense one might ask ***who was responsible for breaking this window?***, meaning ***Who broke the window?***

Comment: "What was responsible for the broken window?" "This baseball was responsible. Yes, I hit the baseball in the direction of the window, but in the end, _I_ didn't break the window, it was the baseball".

Answer (score 1):

[*Professional*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/professional)

> 1.1 Worthy of or appropriate to a professional person; competent, skillful, or assured:
>
> OED

Alternatively:

[*Particular*:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/particular)

> 3.0 Insisting that something should be correct or suitable in every
>   detail; fastidious:

[*Specialized*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/specialized)

ADJECTIVE

> 1.0 Requiring or involving detailed and specific knowledge or training:

[*Exacting:*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exacting)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Making great demands on one’s skill, attention, or other resources:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com

Comment: "Exacting" is very close to what I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: Exacting  looks very much like my suggestion!!

Comment: Yes, it does, sorry I missed that @Josh61. I have moved it to the bottom of my list to confirm your initiative.